# How do I get the transaction hash after calling a smart contract's function in solidity

Tags: solidity

I need to obtain the transaction hash of a Solidity Smart Contract function after triggering the function and store it in a global variable within the Smart Contract.

my solidity code is

```cpp
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import "patient.sol";

contract Doctor_Contract is Patient_Contract { 

    // Patient_Contract patient_contract = new Patient_Contract();

    uint8 doctor_id = 1;

    struct Doctor {
        uint8 doc_id;
        string doctor_name;
        string doctor_email;
        string d_phone_no;
    }

    Doctor[] doctor_record;

    function AddDoctorRecord(string memory doctor_name, string memory doctor_email, 
    string memory d_phone_no ) public onlyadmin {
        doctor_record.push(Doctor(doctor_id,doctor_name, doctor_email, d_phone_no));
        doctor_id++;
    }

    function GetDoctorRecord() public view returns(Doctor[] memory){
        return (doctor_record);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you "invoking a Solidity function"?

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke any transaction through js or any backend, store that transaction in a variable and that variable contains the transaction hash. You can fetch it from there.

For example :

```
let transaction = await  contract.functionname();
```

This `transaction` variable  will contain the transaction hash as well as other details, you can console log it and see what details it contains.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using NodeJs or ReactJs to call the function you can do the following procedure

```
 try {
      const transaction = await contract.methods
        .function()
        .call({ from: accountAddress });
      
      console.log("tx details:", transaction)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

This will console, whole transaction detail and you can get transaction hash from there